# Redux deprecation warning message, breaking site, plugins not updating

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, deprecation-warning

[image]

I have a question to you because I don't have enough knowledge of php and Redux and hope you can help/ advice.

This is the issue, I have Wordpress website with a premium theme, however it seems that the theme maker is unreachable and I am getting this message:

> Deprecated: Function Redux::setHelpTab has been deprecated since
> version Redux 4.3 ! Instead, use Redux::set_help_tab( $opt_name, $tab
> ). in /www/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5383 Deprecated: Function
> Redux::setHelpSidebar has been deprecated since version Redux 4.3!
> Instead, use Redux::set_help_sidebar( $opt_name, $content ). in
> /www/wp-includes/functions.php online 5383

I tried my best to get this fixed, but unfortunately not able, because I am sure where to put:

```
Redux::set_help_tab( $opt_name, $tab );
```

and

```
Redux::set_help_sidebar( $opt_name, $content );
```

I have been reading and watching about Redux and this specific issue, but was not able to find the solution and I am trying to get some assistance, which can point me in the right direction.

Comment: This issue is barely related to Redux, it's entirely in the PHP code. Did you open `wp-includes/functions.php` file and checked what is in the line 5385?

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. Yes please see what is in the attached image, that is what I see, when opening: wp-includes/functions.php

Comment: Great, so this is just where the warning is raised. You may want to search the code for `setHelpTab` and replace with `set_help_tab`, same for the other function. Make sure to have a copy (or even better use source control) just in case something goes wrong